Conditional target of hyperlink or hyperref
I am creating a fillable PDF form wherein, depending on the choice from \ChoiceMenu the sequence of next pages need to be changed. I need to set the target of \hyperlink dynamically, however I could not use JS to achieve this.
Any smart solution?

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you post a minimal working example of what you have so far?
